# Iframe runner with inputable URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, iframe

*Note I am using google app scripts

I am attempting to code a simple program as proof of concept, the concept being a Iframe that responds to the input of a html text box. So far I have looked into the triggers for the form element (I decided to use onsubmit) and researched the changing of an Iframe src. It starts out working, when I load it up it looks like this:

[image: screen grab]

After that though, I type the url in the text box and click submit. It reloads, than displays a completely blank screen. Here is my code:

code.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();
}
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

Index.HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include ('Css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="uri" name="uri"><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="frameS">
    <form>
    <script>
        function frameS() {
          var urv = document.getElementById('uri');
          var ura = urv.value;
          url1 = trim(ura);
        }
        function trim(str){
          return str.replace (/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        }
    </script>
    <iframe allowfullscreen="true" width="600" height="400" id="abc" src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1">sorry, couldn't load</iframe>
    <?!= include ('javascript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript.html

```html
<script>
  Logger.log('hit')
</script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

Css.html *please note that the style sheet is not currently doing anything, I'm just including it for future development

```html
<style>
  /* CSS reset */
 body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
 html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 body {
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 100;
}
 fieldset {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     width: 200px;
}
 legend {
     padding: 0 10px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for your time and would appreciate any feedback on my code, related to the question or not.

Comment: There's likely errors shown in the debugging console. For example, it will complain about `.getElementById(abc)` since it should be `.getElementById("abc")`.

Comment: Have a look at your browser developer consoler.